# Uber api endpoint to fetch rides that are not yet taken

Tags: uber-api

Is there an api endpoint to fetch incomplete rides.I tried using /V1.2/HISTORY, but it will give only completed rides.

This is required to cancel a ride.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Uber API does not have an endpoint to fetch the status of an active ride.